# Вывод графика функции WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть цикл рисующий график функции f(x) =  x * x * x - 10 * x*x - 3 * x + 59 с помощью LineTo. Но при отображении получаются ломанные линии,как это можно исправить?

x,y -координаты центра экрана (500;250)

kx,ky - коэффициенты масштабирования по x и y соответственно(Масштабирование при изменении окна)

i*14 - выравнял ширину графика,без этого очень узко рисует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for( int i = -10;i <= 10;i++){
    LineTo(hdc, x + (i*14)*kx, y - f(i)*ky);            
}
```

Comment: Ну сделайте почаще шаг - типа, `for(double i = -10;i <= 10;i+=0.05)`...

Comment: Даже не подумал об этом,это решило проблему

Comment: Еще в WinAPI есть функции рисования кривых Безье, например `PolyBezier`.